# Illegal State Exception in mediaplayer.prepare android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview, android-bitmap

I am using a method in asynctask in the class VideoSurfaceView.

But I am getting crash.

I tried other ways too but didn't worked. Below is the code:

......

```
     public class VideoSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = "VideoSurfaceView";

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    private String mVideoPath = "";
    private ScreenSaverView.OnVideoPrepareListener onVideoPrepareListener;

    private Bitmap mPreviewBitmap;

    private boolean locking = false;
    private boolean lockResult = false;
    private boolean reading = false;

    public VideoSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        LogD.i(TAG, "init");
        SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder = getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        LogD.i(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
        if (!getVideoPath().isEmpty()) {
            initVideoPlayer();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        LogD.i(TAG, "surfaceChanged");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        LogD.i(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed");
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }

    }


    private void initVideoPlayer() {
        Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
        if (mPreviewBitmap != null && canvas != null) {
            int w = getWidth();
            int h = getHeight();
            Rect src = new Rect(0, 0, mPreviewBitmap.getWidth(), mPreviewBitmap.getHeight());
            Rect dst = new Rect(0, 0, w, h);
            LogD.d(TAG, "drawFirstFrame:view w: " + getWidth() + " h:" + getHeight());
            canvas.drawBitmap(mPreviewBitmap, src, dst, null);
            getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        } else if (canvas != null){
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }

        boolean needClose = onVideoPrepareListener.onPrepare();
        if (needClose) {
            LogD.d(TAG, "initVideoPlayer needClose return: ");
            return;
        }

        LogD.i(TAG, "initFirstPlayer()");
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0, 0);
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(getHolder());
        startPlayFirstVideo();
    }

    private void startPlayFirstVideo() {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, FileCacheMediaDataSource>() {

            @Override
            protected FileCacheMediaDataSource doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                locking = true;
                lockResult = false;
                reading = true;
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        LockResult result = LockManager.getInstance().lock(LockReason.DISK_SCREENSAVER_READ_ACCESS);
                        lockResult = result.isLockSuccess();
                        if (!reading && lockResult) {
                            LockManager.getInstance().unlock(LockReason.DISK_SCREENSAVER_READ_ACCESS);
                        }
                        locking = false;
                    }
                }).start();

                String path = AppConst.SCREEN_SAVER_MEDIA_PATH + mVideoPath;
                FileCacheMediaDataSource dataSource = new FileCacheMediaDataSource(path);
                if (!locking && lockResult) {
                    LockManager.getInstance().unlock(LockReason.DISK_SCREENSAVER_READ_ACCESS);
                }
                reading = false;

                return dataSource;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(FileCacheMediaDataSource dataSource) {
                super.onPostExecute(dataSource);
                if (mMediaPlayer == null) {
                    return;
                }
                if (dataSource.getSize() == -1) {
                    LogD.d(TAG, "showErrorScreenSaver");
                    screenSaverError();
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    // stop and reset media player
                    mMediaPlayer.stop();
                    mMediaPlayer.reset();
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(dataSource);
                    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mMediaPlayer.start();
                        }
                    });
                    mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LogD.i(TAG, "startPlayFirstVideo = " + e.toString());
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void screenSaverError() {
        if (videoSurfaceCallBack != null) {
            videoSurfaceCallBack.onError();
        }
    }


    public String getVideoPath() {
        return mVideoPath;
    }

    public void setOnVideoPrepareListener(ScreenSaverView.OnVideoPrepareListener onVideoPrepareListener) {
        this.onVideoPrepareListener = onVideoPrepareListener;
    }

    public void setPreviewBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
        mPreviewBitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public void setVideoPath(String videoPath) {
        mVideoPath = videoPath;

        Bitmap bitmap = mPreviewBitmap;
        if (bitmap != null) {
            int videoWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
            int videoHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
            float max = Math.max((float) videoWidth / (float) 1024,(float) videoHeight / (float) 520);
            videoWidth = (int) Math.ceil((float) videoWidth / max);
            videoHeight = (int) Math.ceil((float) videoHeight / max);
            LogD.d(TAG, "setVideoPath LayoutParams videoWidth:"+videoWidth+" videoHeight:"+videoHeight);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(videoWidth, videoHeight);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
            setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    }

    private VideoSurfaceCallBack videoSurfaceCallBack;

    public void setVideoSurfaceCallBack(VideoSurfaceCallBack videoSurfaceCallBack) {
        this.videoSurfaceCallBack = videoSurfaceCallBack;
    }

    interface VideoSurfaceCallBack {
        void onError();
    }
}
```

I am getting error as,

```
   12-23 08:28:11.108  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.custom, PID: 7759
    12-23 08:28:11.108  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    12-23 08:28:11.108  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
    12-23 08:28:11.108  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1274)
    12-23 08:28:11.108  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.example.custom.view.VideoSurfaceView$1.onPostExecute(VideoSurfaceView.java:155)
    12-23 08:28:11.108  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.example.custom.view.VideoSurfaceView$1.onPostExecute(VideoSurfaceView.java:106)
    12-23 08:28:11.108  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755)
    12-23 08:28:11.108  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192)
    12-23 08:28:11.108  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772)
    12-23 08:28:11.108  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    12-23 08:28:11.108  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    12-23 08:28:11.108  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    12-23 08:28:11.108  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    12-23 08:28:11.108  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    12-23 08:28:11.108  7759  7759 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

I am getting error in **mMediaPlayer.prepare();**. Kindly let me know where exactly I need to fix this issue.

I tried using mMeiaPlayer.perpareAsync too but didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to prepare the `MediaPlayer` when the `MediaPlayer` is in a wrong state. Check the [MediaPlayer State Diagram](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#state-diagram). The `prepare` or `prepareAsync` methods can be called only if the MediaPlayer is in **Initialized** or **Stopped** state.

Since the `MediaPlayer` state is not accessible, you could use this extension to check what's wrong with your `MediaPlayer` (remember to remove the external player listeners from your code before trying this)

```
import android.content.Context
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.net.Uri
import android.util.Log

class AudioPlayer : MediaPlayer(), MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

    enum class AudioPlayerState {
        IDLE,
        INITIALIZED,
        PREPARING,
        PREPARED,
        STARTED,
        STOPPED,
        PAUSED,
        PLAYBACK_COMPLETED,
        ERROR,
        END
    }

    var playerState: AudioPlayerState? = null
        set(value) {
            Log.d(javaClass.name, "Setting new player state $value")
            field = value
        }

    init {
        playerState = AudioPlayerState.IDLE
        setOnPreparedListener(this)
        setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this)
        setOnCompletionListener(this)
        setOnErrorListener(this)
        setOnInfoListener(this)
    }

    override fun setDataSource(context: Context, uri: Uri) {
        if (playerState != AudioPlayerState.IDLE) Log.e(javaClass.name, "Trying to set data source on player state $playerState")
        super.setDataSource(context, uri)
        playerState = AudioPlayerState.INITIALIZED
    }

    override fun prepare() {
        if (playerState != AudioPlayerState.INITIALIZED && playerState != AudioPlayerState.STOPPED) Log.e(javaClass.name, "Trying to prepare on player state $playerState")
        playerState = try {
            super.prepare()
            AudioPlayerState.PREPARED
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e(javaClass.name, "Exception on audio player prepare ${e.message} with state $playerState")
            AudioPlayerState.ERROR
        }
    }

    override fun prepareAsync() {
        playerState = try {
            super.prepareAsync()
            AudioPlayerState.PREPARING
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e(javaClass.name, "Exception on audio player prepare async ${e.message} with state $playerState")
            AudioPlayerState.ERROR
        }
    }

    override fun start() {
        if (playerState != AudioPlayerState.PREPARED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.STARTED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.PAUSED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.PLAYBACK_COMPLETED
        ) Log.e(javaClass.name, "Trying to start on player state $playerState")
        playerState = try {
            super.start()
            AudioPlayerState.STARTED
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e(javaClass.name, "Exception on audio player start ${e.message} with state $playerState")
            AudioPlayerState.ERROR
        }
    }

    override fun stop() {
        if (playerState != AudioPlayerState.PREPARED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.STARTED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.STOPPED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.PAUSED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.PLAYBACK_COMPLETED
        ) Log.e(javaClass.name, "Trying to stop on player state $playerState")
        playerState = try {
            super.stop()
            AudioPlayerState.STOPPED
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e(javaClass.name, "Exception on audio player stop ${e.message} with state $playerState")
            AudioPlayerState.ERROR
        }
    }

    override fun pause() {
        if (playerState != AudioPlayerState.STARTED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.PAUSED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.PLAYBACK_COMPLETED
        ) Log.e(javaClass.name, "Trying to pause on player state $playerState")
        playerState = try {
            super.pause()
            AudioPlayerState.PAUSED
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e(javaClass.name, "Exception on audio player pause ${e.message} with state $playerState")
            AudioPlayerState.ERROR
        }
    }

    override fun seekTo(msec: Int) {
        if (playerState != AudioPlayerState.PREPARED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.STARTED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.PAUSED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.PLAYBACK_COMPLETED
        ) Log.e(javaClass.name, "Trying to seek to on player state $playerState")
        try {
            super.seekTo(msec)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e(javaClass.name, "Exception on audio player seek to ${e.message} with state $playerState")
            playerState = AudioPlayerState.ERROR
        }
    }

    override fun seekTo(msec: Long, mode: Int) {
        if (playerState != AudioPlayerState.PREPARED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.STARTED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.PAUSED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.PLAYBACK_COMPLETED
        ) Log.e(javaClass.name, "Trying to seek to with mode on player state $playerState")
        try {
            super.seekTo(msec, mode)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e(javaClass.name, "Exception on audio player seek to with mode ${e.message} with state $playerState")
            playerState = AudioPlayerState.ERROR
        }
    }

    override fun getCurrentPosition(): Int {
        if (playerState == null) return 0
        if (playerState != AudioPlayerState.IDLE &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.INITIALIZED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.PREPARED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.STARTED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.PAUSED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.STOPPED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.PLAYBACK_COMPLETED
        ) Log.e(javaClass.name, "Trying to get current position on player state $playerState")
        try {
            return super.getCurrentPosition()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e(javaClass.name, "Exception on audio player current position ${e.message} with state $playerState")
            playerState = AudioPlayerState.ERROR
        }
        return 0
    }

    override fun isPlaying(): Boolean {
        if (playerState == null) return false
        if (playerState != AudioPlayerState.IDLE &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.INITIALIZED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.PREPARED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.STARTED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.PAUSED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.STOPPED &&
            playerState != AudioPlayerState.PLAYBACK_COMPLETED
        ) Log.e(javaClass.name, "Trying to get is playing on player state $playerState")
        try {
            return super.isPlaying()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e(javaClass.name, "Exception on audio player is playing ${e.message} with state $playerState")
            playerState = AudioPlayerState.ERROR
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun reset() {
        playerState = try {
            super.reset()
            AudioPlayerState.IDLE
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e(javaClass.name, "Exception on audio player reset ${e.message} with state $playerState")
            AudioPlayerState.ERROR
        }
    }

    override fun release() {
        playerState = try {
            super.release()
            AudioPlayerState.END
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e(javaClass.name, "Exception on audio player release ${e.message} with state $playerState")
            AudioPlayerState.ERROR
        }
    }

    override fun onPrepared(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
        if (playerState != AudioPlayerState.STARTED) {
            playerState = AudioPlayerState.PREPARED
        }
    }

    override fun onInfo(mp: MediaPlayer?, what: Int, extra: Int): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onError(mp: MediaPlayer?, what: Int, extra: Int): Boolean {
        playerState = AudioPlayerState.ERROR
        return false
    }

    override fun onCompletion(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
        playerState = AudioPlayerState.PLAYBACK_COMPLETED
        seekTo(0)
    }

    override fun onBufferingUpdate(mp: MediaPlayer?, percent: Int) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I have initialized mediaPlayer in onSurfaceCreated but still I am getting an error

Comment: The extension does not fix the error, but it can give you useful logs and you can check the Media Player state to understand what's wrong with your code

Answer (score 0):

According to exception, mediaPlayer in wrong state. Since i cannot see how you have defined the mediaPlayer, i assume you reuse the mediaPlayer. If so, make sure to stop and reset mediaPlayer before set a new dataSource like following in `onPostExecute`;

Read more on here: [mediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer)

```
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(FileCacheMediaDataSource dataSource) {
                super.onPostExecute(dataSource);
                if (mMediaPlayer == null) {
                    return;
                }
                if (dataSource.getSize() == -1) {
                    LogD.d(TAG, "showErrorScreenSaver");
                    screenSaverError();
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    // stop and reset media player
                    mMediaPlayer.stop();
                    mMediaPlayer.reset();

                    // set datasource
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(dataSource);
                    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mp.start();
                        }
                    });
                    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LogD.i(TAG, "startPlayFirstVideo = " + e.toString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: I tried this too but still video behaves as picture. @ddassa

Comment: I added the entire code too.